# Adding JQuery Pre-Loader gif to a script/function

Tags: jquery

How do I add a pre-loder to this script?
I already have the animated gif. When I say preloader, I mean the spinning gif.

```
$(function(){
            // Set starting slide to 1
            var startSlide = 1;
            // Get slide number if it exists
            if (window.location.hash) {
                startSlide = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
            }
            // Initialize Slides
            $('#slides').slides({
                preload: true,
                crossfade: true,
                effect: 'fade',
                fadeEasing: "easeOutQuad",
                fadeSpeed: 400,
                play: 5000,
                pause: 2500,
                hoverPause: true,
                // Get the starting slide
                start: startSlide,
                animationComplete: function(current){
                    // Set the slide number as a hash
                    window.location.hash = '#' + current;
                }
            });
        });
```

Thanks for the knowledge!

Overmars

Comment: What you're doing there will only execute once the whole page is loaded.

Comment: Which jQuery plugin you are using???

Comment: Additional Info: Original writer had the images wrapped in an anchor tag. But I decided to placed the images in the background of the anchor tag. The way the codes are less and the images only load once in the css file. However, this for some reason causes the loading gif to some how disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't what have you altered in your plugin. For an unchanged slidejs plugin to set the spinning gif you have to just specify the `preloadImage`.

> **preloadImage (string)**
>   Name and location of loading image for preloader.
>   Default path is "/img/loading.gif".

An example is

```
$('#slides').slides({
    preload: true,
    preloadImage: '/img/loading.gif',
    play: 5000,
    pause: 2500,
    hoverPause: true
});
```

Comment: I tried that but the gif is not showing up, just curious, will this be because of me not wrapping the pic in an anchor tag and placing the pic in the background of the anchor tag?

Comment: yep. you should be very careful when you edit source of a plugin.

Comment: Thanks Naveen, I removed the images from the background of the anchor tag and placed them directly in the anchor tag and now I can see the preloader Gif. I thought placing them in the background of the gif would allow me to do a Sprite for quick download of the images. Thanks for your time and contribution sir.